# ng-repeat angularjs conflicting whit ng-model

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

i am creating a web app in which i am using angularjs for database conectivity

here is my code

```
<div ng-repeat="x in sonvinrpm">
<input type="Text" ng-model="venuemobile" value="{{x.venuemobile}}" ng-init="venuemobile='{{venuemobile}}'"
</div>
<button ng-click="updfunction()">update</button>
```

on my page load my textbox fetching particular venuemobile from my database(`1234567890`) if i edit the venuemobile and press update the value of venuemobile should be updated

but i am facing the error

```
 missing parameter: venuemobile
```

and i found out this error is appearing because i am using repeater,

when i remove repeater and enter into textbox manually then my database is updating properly,

previously i used ng-repeater for my dropdownlist and table(`because there are multiple data not single data`) in this case i need only one value from database, what should i use instead of `ng-repeat`

Comment: You have typo in that too, just remove {{}}, from :  ng-init="venuemobile='{{venuemobile}}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to call a function to update a $scope variable, since angular uses two way data binding by default, the updated value will be bound to scope. Anyway your HTML should be

```
<input type="Text" ng-model="venuemobile" value="{{venuemobile}}" ng-init="venuemobile='{{venuemobile}}'"
</div>
```

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh give team viewer or create plunker

Comment: password is what ?